# Dowker and neighborhood complexes: reference wanted

Tags: reference-request, simplicial-stuff, simplicial-complexes, bipartite-graphs

Let $R$ be a 0-1 matrix whose rows or columns are maximal.

> **Q1.** Is there a name for such a matrix (or, e.g., a corresponding relation)?

From [0-1 matrix corresponding to an abstract simplicial complex](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/298818/), we know that $R$ corresponds to an abstract simplicial complex, viz. the Dowker complex $D(R)$.

One has maps $\begin{pmatrix} 0 & R \\ R^T & 0 \end{pmatrix} \overset{\pi}{\rightarrow} R \overset{D}{\rightarrow} D(R)$, where $D(R)$ is the Dowker complex of $R$. The involutions $\begin{pmatrix} 0 & R \\ R^T & 0 \end{pmatrix} \overset{\sigma}{\mapsto} \begin{pmatrix} 0 & R^T \\ R & 0 \end{pmatrix}$, $R \overset{T}{\mapsto} R^T$, and $D(R) \overset{*}{\mapsto} D^*(R) := D(R^T)$ (with the last one a homotopy equivalence) are such that $D \circ \pi = \mathcal{N}$, where the RHS indicates the neighborhood complex as in section 2.2 of [Lovász's notes](http://web.cs.elte.hu/~lovasz/kurzusok/topol13.pdf).

[In the electrical engineering and machine learning literature (and ignoring the distinction between an adjacency matrix and a graph), the inverse image of $\pi$ is called a "factor graph."]

> **Q2.** Is there a canonical reference for all of these correspondences that includes the perspective of bipartite graphs?

Note in particular that we immediately get a rich homology theory for bipartite graphs from the Dowker homology of $R$ (or, if the extra step is desired, the simplicial homology of the Dowker complex).

I have found various papers that mention two of the three threads above, e.g., the correspondence between relations and Dowker complexes is in Dowker's original paper and its various cites, and a weighted version is in "[A functorial Dowker theorem and persistent homology of asymmetric networks](https://arxiv.org/abs/1608.05432)." Bipartite graphs and neighborhood complexes are also discussed in "[Construction of and efficient sampling from the simplicial configuration model](https://arxiv.org/abs/1705.10298)". But I haven't found any reference that ties all three together.

Comment: Sorry if it may sound trivial, but what do you mean by "the columns are maximal"?

Comment: @LucaGhidelli No column has all its entries less than or equal to those in another column.