# Have partition functions of abstract simplicial complexes been examined?

Tags: reference-request, zeta-functions, simplicial-complexes, bipartite-graphs

Many complicated probability distributions arising in electrical engineering and machine learning have a simple expression as a sum of products that can also be encoded in a [factor graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factor_graph). The normalizing "partition function" can also be viewed as arising from a corresponding abstract simplicial complex along the lines of [Dowker and neighborhood complexes: reference wanted](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/299959/).

> My question is this: has any work been done that involves such
>   partition (or, say zeta) functions of ASCs?

Comment: NB. Answers that just say "Stanley-Reisner Hilbert series" are not really what I'm looking for, but elaborations on this theme in the spirit of the question would be welcome.

Comment: Also, I would be equally interested in work that involves a "Hilbert series" of a bipartite graph.

Comment: https://arxiv.org/abs/1806.05239

Comment: https://arxiv.org/abs/1102.0316